# Complete and isolated LLVM/musl toolchain

Tags: clang, llvm, toolchain, musl, lld

What I'm trying to achieve is to compile an **GNU independent and isolated** LLVM toolchain using [musl](https://www.musl-libc.org/) as `clib`.

Recently [LLVM 4.0](http://releases.llvm.org/4.0.0/docs/ReleaseNotes.html) has been released with lot's of new cool features, including production ready [LLD](http://lld.llvm.org/), so also the linking step could be handled by LLVM.

More or less the stack is:

- clang
- llvm
- lld
- compiler-rt
- libcxx
- libcxxabi
- musl

Following [this](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Toolchain.html), it is actually possible to do so without much patching or such (apart from compiling `musl`), but sadly, there is no good documentation about that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This might be relevant: http://ellcc.org/

Answer (score 5):

There is an example of using Clang + Musl together to compile "Hello World" in C here: https://github.com/njlr/portable-cxx

It only requires `wget`, `tar` and `make` to be installed. Clang and Musl are downloaded as part of the build process.

The key is to disable the usual include paths using `-nostdinc` and then add the Musl ones using `-isystem`.

Answer (score 3):

I was solving the same problem with my [NGTC](https://github.com/tpimh/ngtc) (Non-GNU toolchain) project. Please take a look at my build scripts and patches.

I used this toolchain to build a small Linux distro without any code from GNU project: [nenuzhnix](https://github.com/tpimh/nenuzhnix).